# How to dismiss UITableView?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview

My app pulls up a uitableview screen when the user clicks a settings button.  I can't figure out how to wire up the request to dismiss with the action.

How do I dismiss this view from within the uitableview?

Setting up view:

```
SettingsController *rootViewController = [[SettingsController alloc]
  initWithStyle:UITableViewStyleGrouped];
UINavigationController *navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] 
  initWithRootViewController:rootViewController];
settingsView = navigationController.view;
settingsView.frame = 
  CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height);
[self.view insertSubview:settingsView atIndex:0];
```

Bringing view to front:

```
- (IBAction)settingsPressed:(id)sender{
[self.view bringSubviewToFront:settingsView];
}
```

Placing view in back:

```
- (void)QuitSettings {
[self.view sendSubviewToBack:settingsView];
}
```

Catching "return" button click in SettingsController:

```
- (void) action:(id) sender{
//[super.view sendSubviewToBack:holdingView];   
// access error [self release];
// nothing [holdingView removeFromSuperview];
// access error [super QuitSettings];
 }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I sounds like you want to be using a Modal view rather than inserting a subview at a particular index.

You should use

```
[self presentModalViewController:myTableViewController animated:YES];
```

where self is the view controller that will be making the call to bring up the table view.

Then you can attach a button or action somewhere on the table view controller that will call

```
[self.parentViewController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

to dismiss the table view controller.

Comment: Smooth.  You handled my immediate question and the unstated one (how do I get rid of the hack I'm using to bring up the uitableview?).

Comment: how do I catch the myTableViewController wasDismissed event?

Comment: look at viewWillDisappear and viewDidDisappear.

Comment: I think viewWillDisappear works at the myTableViewController level.  I'm hoping to catch this from the top level (that called myTableViewController).

Comment: Thanks! That was just what I needed.  I didn't realize mine was set to a pushViewController so when i wanted to close the present view on settings change it just sat there.

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't this work?

```
[settingsView removeFromSuperView]
```